# @javax.persistence.OrderBy for Sorting

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, spring-data

I have two entities.

Entity A:

```
public class A
{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OrderBy("some-property-of-b)
    @OneToMany
    private Set<B> bs;
}
```

Entity B:

```
public class B
{
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}
```

When I am running the server which is JBOSS it is throws me the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor
>   for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by
>   fragment
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be
>   cast to antlr.Token

I am thinking about some conflicting dependencies but not sure. Does anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: Are you sending any other library that the JBoss already has?

Comment: Looks similar - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1014594. The link does provide some workarounds